# YUI getElementById('id').value deprecated?

Tags: javascript, yui

My IDE complains the usage of value like in the below YUI statement is deprecated.. it works, still, what is the proper usage.

```
  var idValue= document.getElementById('id').value;
```

thanks..
Babu

Comment: That statement has nothing to do with YUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid statement, not sure what your IDE is having a problem with here.  Various libraries have shortcuts for this (syntax shortcuts, not *performance* shortcuts), but none of that prevents the core JavaScript functionality from working, it's 100% valid.

I guess it's expecting the YUI style:

```
var element = new YAHOO.util.Element('id');
var idValue = element.get('value');
```

...but either method works, use whichever you want.  I would prefer the shorter core javascript syntax here.

Answer (score 0):

Babu,

As noted, the original code snippet does not use any JS library -- it sounds like the IDE is badly configured.  Nick's answer looks good for YUI 2.  In the newer YUI 3 syntax, you might do this:

```
YUI().use("node", function(Y) {
  var value = Y.one("#id").get("value);
});
```

-Eric